# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'detailsController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to display the artist details when he or she is selected from a list but the error i get in my chrome console says that detailsController is not a function got undefined

**list.html**

```
<section class="artist">
    <div class="search">
        <h1>Artist Directory</h1>
        <label>Search:</label>
        <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for artists" autofocus/>
        <p> </p>
        <label class="formgroup"> by:
            <select ng-model="artistOrder">
                <option value="name">Name</option>
                <option value="reknown">Reknown</option>
            </select>

        </label>
        <label class="formgroup">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" checked/>ascending
        </label>
        <label class="formgroup">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" value="reverse"/> descending

        </label>

    </div>
    <ul class="artistlist">
        <li class="artist cf" ng-repeat="artist in artists | filter: query | orderBy: artistOrder:direction">
            <a href="#/details/{{artists.indexOf(artist)}}">
            <img ng-src="images/{{artist.shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt=""/>

            <div class="info">
                <h2>{{artist.name }}</h2>

                <h3>{{artist.reknown}}</h3>
            </div>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**details.html**

```
<section class="artistinfo">
<div class="artist cf" ng-model="artists">

    <h1>{{artists[whichItem].name}}</h1>
    <div class="info">
        <h3>{{artists[whichItem].reknown}}</h3>
        <img ng-src="images/{{artists[whichItem].shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="bio">{{artists[whichItem].bio}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

**controllers.js**

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

artistControllers.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.artists = data;
        $scope.artistOrder = "name"; // name is selected in orderby

    });
}]);

artistControllers.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.artists = data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    });
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[

    'ngRoute',
    'artistControllers'

]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'listController'
}).
    when('/details/:itemId', {
        templateUrl:'partials/details.html',
        controller:'detailsController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });


}]);
```

Comment: Can you provide plunkr?

Comment: sorry i do not have that